# If for all f $\in C_b(X)$ f attains it's maximum, then X is compact.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

This is working over $(X,d)$ a metric space. I will quickly reproduce the questions in case it hasn't typeset in the title.

If for all f $\in C_b(X)$, f attains it's maximum, then X is compact.

I am familiar with the result that "If every $f \in C(X)$ is bounded then X is compact" and how this is proved (using Tietze's extension theorem). But this result isn't the same. This is not a HW Question but it was sparked after proving that the opposite implication holds.

Comment: By contradiction. Suppose that $f$ fails to attain its maximum. Then take a maximising sequence for $f$, i.e. a sequence $x_n\in X$ such that $f(x_n)\to \sup f$. Can $x_n$ have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'm afraid that that isn't the result I'm looking for. You may have misread the Q.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think this proves the direction $X$ is compact $\implies$ every continuous function attains its maximum, right?

Comment: Oh really, is this wrong? My reasoning is the following. Suppose by contradiction that $X$ is compact and that there is a continuous $f$ such that $\sup f$ is not attained. Construct a sequence as in my previous comment. Since $X$ is compact there is a converging subsequence. And since $f$ is continuous this subsequence is maximising. We conclude that there is a point $x_0$ (the limit point of such subsequence) such that $f(x_0)=\max f$. Contradiction. Do you think it is wrong? I get lost in these contradictions sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is not compact then there exists an unbounded $f$ in $C(X)$.  Therefore
$$
g(x) := \arctan(f(x))
$$
is bounded but does not attain its norm.

Comment: Oh lol, of course. Thank you.

Comment: Nice one! the reason being that $\arctan$ does not attain its supremum anywhere. So this is a property that $\mathbb{R}$ has as a non-compact space and it is inherrited to all non-compact spaces by composing with one such function of $\mathbb{R}$ (just revising the idea of the proof)